# Llive data dynamic update on Highstock chart ( Cannot read property 'info' of undefined) error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

With laravel i created Highcharts from consumed Rest API Link(Spring app) (https://f586c5c5.ngrok.io/api/clients).

This all results are shown statically, now i want to visualise dynamically on charts.

I follow this example of fiddle and tried to implement in my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/md975oLk/23/

But i'm getting this error when i write a code : "Cannot read property 'info' of undefined"
My codepen example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLEyGb          (wait 5 second for charts to show up)
I read highchart documentation but still it not clear to me how to update data on chart.So if some new data are loaded on json i want to visulate it on my charts.I spent 2 day in research for solution and i didn't found it :(

P.S.

In case you declare variables and chart(data) is not updated probably it will happen because i didn't turn on java client application so it showing just same data.I not able to keep application truned on because lack of memory on my harddisk. Only monitoring app is truned on so link is working!

```
 @endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **addPoint** method, you can only add one point to series - you try add multiple. You should consider using **setData** method.

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Thansk for answer i put `SetData` but still it not do update of charts

Comment: Hi Nenad, charts do update, but you have fixed values. Please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v2L6adro/

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLEyGb  my working example,  thank you for answer i really appreciate. Yes currently values are fixed but when i turn on my client java app it startsto receive a new values data on rest api link(json).So in `client.memory.sort();` i have values(memory_usage, timestamp) and put in series object and in setData function.Now it happening after 3 seconds my series on chart just disappear.Please help me if you know i spent 3 days with this problem and still can't figure how to solve it ? :(

Comment: Hi Nenad, Of course I will try to help you. Your example does not work and there is error: ``Failed to load resource`, can you fix it?

Comment: This is my last example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqZERG . I call again rest api link on each 5 seconds inside event function,i  made parsing of data and wrote SetData function but now series disappear !

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not reproduce your problem, because you get data from localhost. From your description, I can deduce that your way of working is correct, but I'm wondering why in `setData` method you use data from the existing series? You should set new data received from the server. Please take a look at this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t4zn0c7x/, it should help.

Comment: Well i tried to share my localhost through ssh tunnel(ngrok app) ..So if i want to use data from existing series i should use addPoint ? I tried that but i'm getting error  " Highcharts Error #20
Can't add object point configuration to a long data series". https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLyOOL Thanks again for helping me, i0m doing this for my master work and i'm really upset because it not going very well :(

Comment: No, you should use `setData`, but with combined data from series and new data from server. Method `addPoint` is used for add only one new point to the existing series. Please analyze exactly my example. If you still have problems, you can prepare an example with hard-coded data, so we can simulate current case.

Comment: I tried and unfortunetly i didn't made it. Here is example with hard-coded data, i hope it will help...  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEpKVw?editors=0010

Comment: Hi Nenad, thank you for the example above, now it is much simpler to work with your problem. In your case, you use `setData` twice for each chart. In general, this method removes all data from the series and set new one. So before `setData` you should combine the actual data with new data (also please read about `updatePoints` parameter in API). Here is a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ecgzdkb6/ I modified the data a bit to better present the solution.

Comment: I want to thank you, you save me this time ! It works, only when i call function each second my lap top slow down(i will try on better machine)Thanks again I really appreciate ! :)